# Are apt-cache depends/rdepends always inverse

Tags: debian, apt, apt-cache

Does it make sense that `apt-cache depends/rdepends` are not always inverse to each other?

For instance, I have a host where `apt-cache rdepends liblognorm1` lists these reverse dependencies: `rsyslog liblognorm-dev`, but `apt-cache depends rsyslog` does not include `liblognorm1` (only `liblognorm5`) in its dependencies.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a feature, and a necessary one, and your example is already a very good example.

A libraries older version might be depended on by an older version of a program. That programs current version will not depend on that older version of the library though. It may depend on a newer version of the library, or may have dropped/replaced that dependency.

The same program name can appear in the depends/rdepends output, but it can be referring to different versions. Use `apt-cache showpkg`, its output is a bit more clear about which version you are looking at and which other other packages are required or broken in which versions.

Comment: The host had `liblognorm1`, `liblognorm5`, `rsyslog` (but not `liblognorm-dev`) installed. So I have concluded that it was safe to purge `liblognorm1`.

Comment: Agreed, except in the case of `liblognorm1` it was marked as manual and so `apt-get autoremove` did not pick it up. This seems to be the default setting on a plain-vanilla Debian Jessie installation.